# Azure sdk for iot device connection in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

for android I found com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client:1.26.0 for IoT device connection with android ,Is there any implementation for IoT device connection using connection string in flutter.

Comment: Looking for same solution!

Comment: I implemented in Java supported sdk itself, at present its the easiest method.